Error when trying to upload an SQL file using the source command in MySQL
I am a fairly new student currently enrolled in Python and SQL for Data Science course from a website called Scaler. As part of the course, I am trying to understand the concepts of MySQL.
The instructor provided an SQL file named imdb.sql and demonstrated how to upload it to MySQL using the source command. However, whenever I try to do the same, I encounter the following error:
ERROR:
mysql> source D:\sqlpracticescaler\imdb.sql;
--------------
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe  Ver 8.0.37 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Connection id:          10
Current database:       imdb
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.37 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Binary data as:         Hexadecimal
Uptime:                 9 hours 23 min 57 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 31  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 145  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 64  Queries per second avg: 0.000
--------------

ERROR:
Unknown command '\i'.
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'D:qlpracticescaler\imdb.sql', error: 2

I have double-checked the file path and ensured the file exists.
Additional Information:
MySQL version: mysql  Ver 8.0.37 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
Operating system: Windows 64-bit operating system
Size of imdb.sql file: 150,181 KB
What could be causing this error, and how can I successfully upload the imdb.sql file to my MySQL database using the source command?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Escape the slashes: source D:\\sqlpracticescaler\\imdb.sql; (or use /)

42 years of confusion caused by Microsoft's decision to use backlsash as their default directory separator.

This is a typical typo, if you read carefully your error message. Failed to open file 'D:qlpracticescaler\imdb.sql' And you have D:\sqlpracticescaler\imdb.sql; - Missing \s.
